# injecting a python class member function

Tags: python, functional-programming

The following code works in python3, but not python2. To be clear, I am trying to inject/monkey patch a member function from another class (Class1) into the target class (Class2) so that the function uses appropriate member attributes from self.

Why does it work in python3, and what else can I do to get the desired behavior in python2?

```
class Parent:
  def foo(self):
    print("foo of class Parent: instance " + self.__class__.__name__)

  def __init__(self):
    self.d = {"foo": self.__class__.foo}

  def bar(self):
    self.d['foo'](self)
    self.d['foo'] = Child1.foo
    self.d['foo'](self)

class Child1(Parent):
  def foo(self):
    print("foo of class Child1: instance " + self.__class__.__name__)

class Child2(Parent):
  pass

Child2().bar()
```

Comment: For one thing, declare `class Parent(object):`. I'm not sure if it's related to your problem but it sticks out to me. In Python 2 you need to declare root classes as subclasses of `object` to make them 'new-style'.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3; it raises `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Because `self.foo = Child1.foo(self)` just calls `foo` and stores the return value, which is `None`, as `self.foo`, and then tries to call that `None`.

Comment: Anyway, what are you actually trying to inject here? Do you want `Child1.foo` bound to `self` even if `self` isn't a `Child1`, or `Child1.foo` bound to some `Child1` instance somewhere, or a function that calls `Child1.foo(self)` or `some-child-one-instance.foo()`, or…? What is the intended output?

Comment: Right, i think what you want is `self.foo = Child1.foo` and then next line `self.foo(self)` (since it will no longer pass that automatically), but not sure why you're calling the child in the parent to begin with...

Comment: Sorry I modified in an attempt to simplify my question and it broke it. Fixed now

Comment: I want Child2().foo() to print: "foo of class Child1: instance Child2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do here is to call the unbound method `Child2.foo` with a `self` that isn't a `Child2`.

This is illegal, and Python 2 will detect that and raise a `TypeError` that explains exactly what's wrong:

```
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with Child1 instance as first argument (got Child2 instance instead)
```

In Python 3, there are no unbound method objects; unbound methods are just plain old functions. So they can't check that you're trying to do anything illegal. And then, because you aren't actually using the fact that `self` is a `Child2` inside the `foo` method, you get away with it.

---

But you can't inject methods that actually use the `Child2`-ness of `Child2` this way; they'll just end up raising a `TypeError` or `AttributeError` or calling the wrong methods. It will only work for methods that had no reason to be methods in the first place.

---

If you really want this behavior in Python 2 anyway, you can get it by extracting the function out of the unbound method:

```
    self.d['foo'] = Child1.foo.__func__
```

(If you want to work with even older 2.x, use `im_func` instead of `__func__` there.)

Now, it's not a method at all—and if you tried to actually bind it to `self` with the descriptor protocol or by constructing a `MethodType` instead, you'd get the same old `TypeError`. But it is a function, and you can call it with whatever argument you want as a function. And, because your function doesn't do anything with that `self` parameter that requires it to be a `Child2`, it will work.

---

While we're at it, you almost certainly want `Parent` to be a new-style class here. And you probably want to use the same code in Python 2 and Python 3, not different code for the same behavior in both. So:

```
class Parent(object): # makes it a new-style class in 2.x as well as 3.x
  def foo(self):
    print("foo of class Parent: instance " + self.__class__.__name__)

  def __init__(self):
    self.d = {"foo": self.__class__.foo}

  def bar(self):
    self.d['foo'](self)
    # Gets __func__ if it's an unbound method (2.x), leaves it alone if not (3.x)
    self.d['foo'] = getattr(Child1.foo, '__func__', Child1.foo)
    self.d['foo'](self)

class Child1(Parent):
  def foo(self):
    print("foo of class Child1: instance " + self.__class__.__name__)

class Child2(Parent):
  pass

Child2().bar()
```